# How do I revert from generate:resource while using JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, generator

How do I revert from generate:resource while using  `JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators` ?

Is there a shortcut to remove the installed resource through a command, something like the inverse of the statement below ?

```
php artisan generate:resource post --fields="title:string, body:text"
```

I have successfully installed & created a resource using the generator in https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators and watching the tutsplus video https://tutsplus.com/lesson/running-migrations/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no shortcut - you need to remove the files manually. If you are using Git (or similar version control) you can just 'roll back'.

Otherwise you need to delete:

- Post Migration table creation
- Model/Post.php
- Views/Posts/*
- Controllers/PostController
- Seeds/PostsTableSeeder.php
- Tests/Controllers/PostsControllerTest.php
- Remove postseeding from databaseseeder.php
- Update routes.php to remove Route::resource('posts');

Comment: What do you mean by 'roll back' ?

Comment: revert to your previous commit - before you used the resource generator